Table doesn't center even with \centering
I am trying to centre a table andd make it fit on the page.
I have tried to use \centering to no avail.
Currently my page looks like this:

Here is the corresponding code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} % Default value: 6pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % Default value: 1
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
        \hline
        & Translations & Lorentz Transformations & Dilitataions & Special Conformal Transformations\\
        \hline
        $\delta x_\mu = v_\mu$ & $a_\mu$ & $\omega_{\mu\nu} x_\nu$ & $\lambda x_\mu$ & $(b_\mu x^2 -  2 x_\mu)$ \\
        \hline
        Generators & $P_\mu$ & $J_{\mu\nu}$ & $D$ & $K_\mu$\\
        \hline
        Dimensions & $d$ & $\frac{1}{2} d(d-1)$ & $1$ & $d$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Infinitesimal conformal transformations, their corresponding generators and their dimensions.}
    \label{table:1}
    \endgroup
\end{table}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! It's because your table is larger than the page.

Your table is too wide. Use a legend for the long headers.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\captionsetup{position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% local command for the legend
\newcommand{\legend}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize #1} \\
}

\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
& T & LT & D & SCT \\
\midrule
$\delta x_\mu = v_\mu$ &
  $a_\mu$ & $\omega_{\mu\nu} x_\nu$ &
  $\lambda x_\mu$ &
  $(b_\mu x^2 -  2 x_\mu)$ \\
\addlinespace
Generators & $P_\mu$ & $J_{\mu\nu}$ & $D$ & $K_\mu$ \\
\addlinespace
Dimensions & $d$ & $\frac{1}{2} d(d-1)$ & $1$ & $d$\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\legend{T: Translations; LT: Lorentz transformations; D: Dilatations;}
\legend{SCT: Special Conformal Transformations}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Infinitesimal conformal transformations, their corresponding generators and their dimensions.}
\label{table:1}

\end{table}

\end{document}


You could also transpose the table:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\captionsetup{position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% local command for the legend
\newcommand{\legend}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize #1} \\
}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
& $\delta x_\mu = v_\mu$ & Generators & Dimensions \\
\midrule
Translations & $a_\mu$ & $P_\mu$ & $d$ \\
\addlinespace
Lorentz Transformations & $\omega_{\mu\nu} x_\nu$ & $J_{\mu\nu}$ & $\frac{1}{2} d(d-1)$ \\
\addlinespace
Dilatations &  $\lambda x_\mu$ & $D$ & $1$ \\
\addlinespace
Special Conformal Transformations & $(b_\mu x^2 -  2 x_\mu)$ & $K_\mu$ & $d$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Infinitesimal conformal transformations, their corresponding 
  generators and their dimensions.}
\label{table:1}

\end{table}

\end{document}



As pointed out by @jlab, it's because your table is too wide.
Here is a solution using your settings and the tabularray package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
  
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,
        colsep=10pt,
        stretch=2,
        colspec={@{}ccX[c]cX[c]@{}},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries}}
      \toprule
      & Translations & Lorentz Transformations & Dilatations & Special Conformal Transformations\\
      \midrule
      $\delta x_\mu = v_\mu$ & $a_\mu$ & $\omega_{\mu\nu} x_\nu$ & $\lambda x_\mu$ & $(b_\mu x^2 -  2 x_\mu)$ \\
      Generators & $P_\mu$ & $J_{\mu\nu}$ & $D$ & $K_\mu$\\
      Dimensions & $d$ & $\frac{1}{2} d(d-1)$ & $1$ & $d$\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Infinitesimal conformal transformations, their corresponding generators and their dimensions.}
    \label{table:1}
  \end{table}
  
\end{document}



BTW, the colsep parameter drastically reduces the available space…
